# event.key spacebar works not correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I have a page with multiple buttons. When I press spacebar it runs the function. But if I press  button x and again spacebar it runs the function of button x. How can I fix that?

```js
const x = str => console.log(str);
const spacebar = () => console.log('space');

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === '1') {
    x(event.key);
  }
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    spacebar();
  }
})
```

```html
<button onclick="x('button')"> x </button>
<button onclick="spacebar()"> spacebar </button>
```

Comment: You bind spacebar to the document. So if you do not want the code to check it, you need to use stopPropagation on the buttons

Comment: I made you a working snippet.

Comment: @mplungjan read the question again....

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, I removed half of my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code runs on keydown, and spacebar presses the x button on keyup. You could remove the focus away from any other thing on the document, just to make sure space is not going to do something else.

```js
const x = str => console.log(str);
const spacebar = () => console.log('space');

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === '1') {
    x(event.key);
  }
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    spacebar();
    document.activeElement.blur(); // I just added this line
  }
})
```

```html
<button onclick="x('button')"> x </button>
<button onclick="spacebar()"> spacebar </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default browser behavior. Because your x button has the focus it runs again when pressing space in for example Google Chrome.

```js
const x = str => console.log(str);
const spacebar = () => console.log('space');

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === '1') {
    x(event.key);
  }
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    event.preventDefault();
    spacebar();
  }
})
```

```html
<button onclick="x('button')"> x </button>
<button onclick="spacebar()"> spacebar </button>
```